# Unable to create signed AAB / APK for release build type: Unresolved reference viewModels

Tags: android, dagger-hilt

I can create the debug APK and AAB but unable to do the same for the release build type. I have Google GMS in my Gradle files and the app compiles and deploys to the emulator without problems. But when it comes to creating a signed AAB, the IDE errors out with `Unresolved reference viewModels` and then lists out every single one of my `@AndroidEntryPoint` files (Fragments) that have Hilt doing the dependency injection. For example, one of those files has

```
private val viewModel: MyViewModel by viewModels()
```

and it's such lines that are being pointed out as being problematic.

How and why? Or where exactly is the problem?

Comment: A little bit more information about your gradle file dependencies and the classes which miss dependencies would help. Thanks

Comment: Hey @zeg can you tell me what you think could be missing in my Gradle files given the situation that I'm in? Because I'm thinking if there really was a problem with missing dependencies, then the app wouldn't compile or launch in the emulator in the first place?

Comment: Or in other words, if there's a problem with my Gradle dependencies, then how come I can generate a signed bundle for the debug build but not the release build?